# How to wait for a specified time between parts of code in Java?

Tags: java, applet, awt, sleep, wait

I have fairly simple question I didn't see properly answered anywhere.

I'm designing a Java applet using java.awt. What I'm trying to do is to have Java wait a few seconds between executing different parts of code in a method for a simple graphical animation.

So it goes like this:

```
runAnimation() {

// draw red shapes

// wait 2 seconds so the shapes remain visible

// set color of shapes to green and repaint

}
```

As suggested elsewhere, if I use something like

```
try {

// do first task

Thread.sleep(2000);

// do second task

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
```

the program only shows the results of the second task after waiting 2 seconds ie I never see the red shapes. I want to see the red shapes for two seconds and then have them set to blue and so on.

Comment: I'm designing an Applet that uses java.awt and I'm going to have more than ten tasks, with a pause between each of them.

Comment: Edit your question and add this to the question text as this information is too important to be buried in comments and not in the question. Also update your question tags to include this. Also, consider posting more relevant code, including your drawing code.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what GUI / graphics library you're using which is key information. If Swing or AWT, then use a Swing Timer to do your pausing. You should not use `Thread.sleep(...)` for this as you would put the GUI's event thread to sleep, causing the whole application to freeze.

e.g.,

```
someColor = Color.RED;
int delay = 2000;
repaint()
Timer swingTimer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        someColor = Color.GREEN;
        repaint();
    }
});
swingTimer.setRepeats(false);
swingTimer.start();
```

Comment: Can I use that timer code several times to have pauses between several tasks such as:

// color red
// wait 2 secs, set to green, repaint
// wait 2 secs, set to blue, repaint
etc?

Comment: @user3862572: yes. Then get rid of the `setRepeats(false)` section. Please consider improving your question, providing all the relevant and important information necessary for us to fully understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I can't post the drawing code at the moment because I don't really have it yet. However, can you post an example of using the swing timer to carry out three consecutive tasks for example?